# could not concatenate the string imported another text file

Tags: python

constant.txt:

```
CONSTANT_PATH=https://www.xxx.aaa
PERMANENT_LOCAL_PATH=/folder/x/y/z
```

read_constant.py:

```
file = open("constant.txt", "r").read().splitlines()
constant = file[0].split("=")[1]
permanent = file[1].split("=")[1]
```

concatenate.py:

```
import read_constant

path = read_constant.constant + read_constant.permanent
print(path)
```

Output:

```
"https://www.xxx.aaa""/folder/x/y/z"
```

Expected:

```
https://www.xxx.aaa/folder/x/y/z
```

I know is a very basic stuff but I really dont know why it became like the current output. Please help.

SORRY please disregard this questions. I forgot to save my text file.

Comment: You didn't do anything to remove the quotes, why are you surprised that they're in the output?

Comment: I don't see any way you'd get that result when you remove the quotes from the file.

Comment: I tried your code, I got the expected result.

Comment: Yes, I already updated my post and said that I forgot to save my text file thats why mine didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F strings are very powerful in python 3.6+

so you can do something like:

```
path = f"{read_constant.constant}{read_constant.permanent}"
```

Comment: How will this remove the double quotes from the input file?

Comment: Sorry, I actually removed the quites.

Comment: oops didn't realize that was a text file at first, but without the quotes this will work and I believe it is more efficient

Comment: I tried your method and also removed the quotes. It seems like I getting the same as well.

Comment: I am so sorry. IT WAS MY BAD!! I forgot to save the text file.

Comment: did you save your file after changing it? I don't see how